# log4j type GenericObjectPool does not take parameters

Tags: log4j, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I am trying to configure log4j for logging to database using JDBCAppender by referring to the below link.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender

However I am getting the error "type GenericObjectPool does not take parameters". could some one please help me rectify this error?

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error">


 <Appenders>
    <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="LOGGING.APPLICATION_LOG">
      <ConnectionFactory class="net.example.db.ConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
      <Column name="EVENT_ID" literal="LOGGING.APPLICATION_LOG_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL" />
      <Column name="EVENT_DATE" isEventTimestamp="true" />
      <Column name="LEVEL" pattern="%level" />
      <Column name="LOGGER" pattern="%logger" />
      <Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%message" />
      <Column name="THROWABLE" pattern="%ex{full}" />
    </JDBC>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

ConnectionFactory.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;

public class ConnectionFactory {
    private static interface Singleton {
        final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
    }

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionFactory() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", "logging");
        properties.setProperty("password", "abc123"); // or get properties from some configuration file

        GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>(); //Error: type GenericObjectPool does not take parameters
        DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
                "jdbc:mysql://example.org:3306/exampleDb", properties
        );
        new PoolableConnectionFactory(
                connectionFactory, pool, null, "SELECT 1", 3, false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        );

        this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
    }

    public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: same problem, any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been resolved by myself.

I have added maven dependency it working fine for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```