# Java log4j2 "GenericObjectPool does not take parameters"

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j2

I'm having the same problem as the user here: 
[log4j type GenericObjectPool does not take parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714311/log4j-type-genericobjectpool-does-not-take-parameters) but I've been unable to find an answer to this problem. Log4j2 works when appending to a rollingfile but the method listed here : 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html gives me the error
"GenericObjectPool does not take Parameters"

```
package database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;

public class ConnectionFactory {
 private static interface Singleton {
  final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
 }

 private final DataSource dataSource;

 private ConnectionFactory() {
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.setProperty("user", "root");
  properties.setProperty("password", "tiger");

        GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>();
        DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
    "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/logging", properties);
  new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, pool, null,
    "SELECT 1",3, false, false,
    Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
  );

  this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
 }

 public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
  return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
 }
}
```

Comment: same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by myself.

I have added maven dependency it working fine for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Very well, can you accept your answer by checking the checlmark (`✔`) next to the answer please?